# Row size too large

Tags: mysql

Error:

> Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

This is the table I'm trying to create:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client_details (
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
client_description VARCHAR(1024),
reuse_refresh_tokens BOOLEAN DEFAULT true NOT NULL,
dynamically_registered BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
allow_introspection BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
id_token_validity_seconds BIGINT DEFAULT 600 NOT NULL,
client_id VARCHAR(256),
client_secret VARCHAR(2048),
access_token_validity_seconds BIGINT,
refresh_token_validity_seconds BIGINT,

application_type VARCHAR(256),
    client_name VARCHAR(256),
token_endpoint_auth_method VARCHAR(256),
subject_type VARCHAR(256),

logo_uri VARCHAR(2048),
policy_uri VARCHAR(2048),
client_uri VARCHAR(2048),
tos_uri VARCHAR(2048),

jwks_uri VARCHAR(2048),
jwks VARCHAR(8192),
sector_identifier_uri VARCHAR(2048),

request_object_signing_alg VARCHAR(256),
user_info_signed_response_alg VARCHAR(256),
user_info_encrypted_response_alg VARCHAR(256),
user_info_encrypted_response_enc VARCHAR(256),

id_token_signed_response_alg VARCHAR(256),
id_token_encrypted_response_alg VARCHAR(256),
id_token_encrypted_response_enc VARCHAR(256),
token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg VARCHAR(256),

default_max_age BIGINT,
require_auth_time BOOLEAN,
created_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
initiate_login_uri VARCHAR(2048),
clear_access_tokens_on_refresh BOOLEAN DEFAULT true NOT NULL,

UNIQUE (client_id)
);
```

Comment: Row size too large = Database not normalized

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of columns that are long VARCHARs. Do you really need them to be that long?

Anyway, I tried your SQL statement and it worked fine for me.

The difference is that I have set:

```
innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_default_row_format=dynamic
```

Depending on your MySQL version, you may also need to set:

```
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
```

These options change the way InnoDB stores VARCHAR, BLOB, and TEXT columns, moving more of their content off of the main page for the row, and onto extra pages. This ends up allowing you define more columns.